# How can i combine 2 data in 1 array with different value?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I have a function where will join 2 data with the same weight in 1 array. My target is how I can join them with a different value? I have a default value that is equal to 15 for the difference.
Additional: I need to put a restriction. Only less than or greater than 15 weight differences should be in the array. If it exceeds, then it shouldn't be in the same array.

For example:

> entryID:1 weight:1900 and entryID:2 1915 will be in array 1... entryID:3 weight:1915 and entryID:4 1920 will be in array 2.

//This current snippet joins 2 data in 1 array if they have the same weight. My target is to join 2 data also in 1 array but with different weights.

```js
const source = [{
    entryID: 1,
    entryName: 'player1',
    weight: 1900,
    
  },
  {
    entryID: 2,
    entryName: 'player2',
    weight: 1915,
   
  },
  {
    entryID: 3,
    entryName: 'player3',
    weight: 1915,
  
  },
  {
    entryID: 4,
    entryName: 'player4',
    weight: 1920,
  
  },
  {
    entryID: 5,
    entryName: 'player5',
    weight: 1950,
    
  },
  {
    entryID: 6,
    entryName: 'player6',
    weight: 1965,
   
  },




  ]


  const combine = (source) => {
    return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (acc[curr.weight]) {
        const levelArr = acc[curr.weight];
        const last = levelArr[levelArr.length - 1];
        if (last.length === 2) {
          levelArr.push([curr])
        } else {
          last.push(curr)
        }
      } else {
        acc[curr.weight] = [
          [curr]
        ];
      }
      return acc;
    }, {})
  };


  var result = combine(source)
  var html = ""
  var keys = Object.keys(result) //if there are more than one keys i.e : 2..

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  result[keys[i]].forEach(function(val) {

    val.forEach(function(value, index) {

     
        var entryIDs = index == 0 ? "entryIDM[]" : "entryIDW[]"
        var handlers = index == 0 ? "handlerM[]" : "handlerW[]"
        var weights = index == 0 ? "weightM[]" : "weightW[]"
        html += `<input type="text" name="${entryIDs}" value="${value.entryID}"> 
                 <input type="text" name="${handlers}" value="${value.entryName}">
                 <input type="text" name="${weights}" value="${value.weight}">
                 `
    })
    })
    
    
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html 

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

My expected output:

```
{
  1900_1915: [[{
  entryID: 1,
  entryName: "player1",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  entryID: 2,
  entryName: "player2",
  weight: 1915
{
  1915_1920: [[{
  entryID: 3,
  entryName: "player3",
  weight: 1915
}, {
  entryID: 4,
  entryName: "player4",
  weight: 1920
}
```

Comment: can you add the expected output to the question?

Comment: Your requirement is still unclear. Your sentence "My target is to join 2 data also in 1 array but with different weight." is unclear. If you want to join an array, you must want something common, right? Your current logic is correct based on the same weight. Please add your expected output or elaborate more.

Comment: This is my expected output:

{
  1900_1915: [[{
  entryID: 1,
  entryName: "player1",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  entryID: 2,
  entryName: "player2",
  weight: 1915
{
  1915_1920: [[{
  entryID: 3,
  entryName: "player3",
  weight: 1915
}, {
  entryID: 4,
  entryName: "player4",
  weight: 1920

Comment: @HardikShah I'm sorry if i make you confused.   On my current function. I can join 2 data in 1 array with the same weight. But for my next target. I want to join 2 data with different value. The difference should not exceed to 15. The reason i provided my old code is because i think it's near to my target. I just need to add some functions in order to make it. I'm sorry, i'm newbie to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. You can adjust the `difference` value that is used to combine data.

```js
const source = [
  { entryID: 1,entryName: 'player1', weight: 1900 },
  { entryID: 2, entryName: 'player2', weight: 1915 },
  { entryID: 3, entryName: 'player3', weight: 1915 },
  { entryID: 4, entryName: 'player4', weight: 1920 },
  { entryID: 5, entryName: 'player5', weight: 1950 },
  { entryID: 6, entryName: 'player6', weight: 1965 },
]

function newCombine(data, difference) {
  let nonMatched = [...data]
  const groups = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < nonMatched.length - 1; i++) {
    const first = nonMatched[i]

    inner: for (let j = nonMatched.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
      const second = nonMatched[j]
      const delta = Math.abs(first.weight - second.weight)

      if (delta <= difference) {
        const groupKey = `${first.weight}_${second.weight}`
        groups[groupKey] = [first, second]
        nonMatched = nonMatched.filter(
          obj => obj.entryID != first.entryID && obj.entryID != second.entryID
        )
        i = -1
        break inner
      }
    }
  }
  return { ...groups, ...nonMatched }
}

const a = newCombine(source, 15)
console.log(a)
```

**EDIT:**

In the above snippet, weight value is being used set a key for the grouped data. This is going to cause issues if there are multiple players with the same weight value. The following input:

```
const source = [
  { entryID: 1, entryName: 'player1', weight: 1900 },
  { entryID: 2, entryName: 'player2', weight: 1915 },
  { entryID: 3, entryName: 'player3', weight: 1915 },
  { entryID: 4, entryName: 'player4', weight: 1915 },
  { entryID: 5, entryName: 'player5', weight: 1915 },
]
```

will output:

```
{
  '0': { entryID: 1, entryName: 'player1', weight: 1900 },
  '1915_1915': [
    { entryID: 3, entryName: 'player3', weight: 1915 },
    { entryID: 4, entryName: 'player4', weight: 1915 }
  ]
}
```

Which resulted in some entries being deleted. So it would be better to use a more unique value for the keys such as `entryID`:

```
const groupKey = `${first.entryID}_${second.entryID}`
```

**EDIT 2:**

If players with the same `entryName` should not be matched than the condition can be changed to:

```
if (delta <= difference && first.entryName !== second.entryName) { 
...
}
```

```js
const source = [
  { entryID: 1, entryName: 'player1', weight: 1915 },
  { entryID: 3, entryName: 'player2', weight: 1910 },
  { entryID: 2, entryName: 'player1', weight: 1920 },
  { entryID: 5, entryName: 'player1', weight: 1910 },
  { entryID: 4, entryName: 'player2', weight: 1920 },
  { entryID: 6, entryName: 'player1', weight: 1915 },
]

function newCombine(data, difference) {
  let nonMatched = [...data]
  const groups = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < nonMatched.length - 1; i++) {
    const first = nonMatched[i]

    inner: for (let j = nonMatched.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
      const second = nonMatched[j]
      const delta = Math.abs(first.weight - second.weight)

      if (delta <= difference && first.entryName !== second.entryName) {
        const groupKey = `${first.weight}_${second.weight}`
        groups[groupKey] = [first, second]
        nonMatched = nonMatched.filter(
          obj => obj.entryID != first.entryID && obj.entryID != second.entryID
        )
        i = -1
        break inner
      }
    }
  }
  return { ...groups, ...nonMatched }
}


const a = newCombine(source, 15)
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Wow. This looks great. I'll try it on my end tomorrow. I hope you can wait for me. Thank you so much. I will upvote this for now. :D

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Can i have another question? How can i avoid the duplicate of player name in 1 array? Player with the same name shouldn't be matched. 

https://prnt.sc/1ym4jup    (If the screenshot is broken here's another screenshot https://snipboard.io/F1DNfQ.jpg)

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer The condition that checks for `difference` value can be updated to also check if the two players being compared have the same `entryName`. I updated the answer and included the condition in the last snippet.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. Saviour.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to group them by their weight. Then you can use the same logic when you check if the list has the same weight.

You don't need to check if they have them same weight, because the dictionary will have their weight as a key.

```
const combine = (source) => {
    return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const wList = acc[curr.weight] || [];
      wList.push(curr);
      acc[curr.weight] = wList;

      return acc;
    }, {})
  };
```

If you need input validation:

```
const combine = (source) => {
    return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      // If not greater or less than 15, means not 15
      if (curr.weight != 15) {
         return acc;
      }

      // values here are valid
      const wList = acc[curr.weight] || [];
      wList.push(curr);
      acc[curr.weight] = wList;

      return acc;
    }, {})
  };
```

Comment: Based on what i need to do, i need to put a restriction. Only greater than or less than equal in 15 with weight difference should be in the same array. If it exceeds, then it shouldn't be in the same array.

Where do i need to put that restriction? Thank you. Appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure I understand now. If you need to only store weights in that range, then you add `if` statement before the `push` call. If you need to limit the list size, maybe you can first map, the run reduce another time to create an additional key.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. I'll try it on my end tomorrow. Will keep you updated. Thank you so much again